# Report time with crontab

Tags: python

I wrote a naive script to report time hourly by playing bell.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

bell_sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/me/Music/audio/bell.wav")
play(bell_sound)
```

Change mode `u+x`

Set cron to implement it hourly  (Test it very minute)

*/1 6-23 * * * /home/gaowei/Music/src/report_time.py &> /\
dev/null

Then check from the syslog that it is correctly executed

```
Jul 10 23:28:01 alpha CRON[10228]: (me) CMD (~/Music/src/report_time.py &> /dev/null)
Jul 10 23:29:01 alpha CRON[10242]: (me) CMD (~/Music/src/report_time.py &> /dev/null)
Jul 10 23:30:01 alpha CRON[10271]: (me) CMD (~/Music/src/report_time.py &> /dev/null)
```

However, why did it silence  and mute even thought it is implemented.

Updated, it works as expected manually

```
$ ./report_time.py 
Input #0, wav, from '/tmp/tmpn6zo0wya.wav':   0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: 00:00:01.62, bitrate: 176 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11025 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 176 kb/s
   1.43 M-A: -0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

updated:

[image]

and other commands does not work either

```
## Report time 2
*/10 6-23 * * *  cvlc /home/me/Music/audio/bell.wav &\
> /dev/null

*/1 6-23 * * *  vlc /home/me/Music/audio/bell.wav &> \
/dev/null
```

-UUU:----F1  crontab        Bot L40    (Fundamental) -----
(No changes need to be saved)

Comment: Does the script work as expected if you run it manual?

Comment: yes, see my update. @0stone0

Comment: Does the crontab runs as the same user that can run the script manual? Maybe the crontab user cant access the file.  See [fixing the crontab user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script). 
Otherwise, try to capture the 'output' 
`*/1 6-23 * * * /home/gaowei/Music/src/report_time.py > /tmp/res.txt 2>&1`

Comment: It might be strange limit on  function of crontab @0stone0

Comment: Try adding the `python` path in the crontab. 
`*/1 6-23 * * *  /usr/bin/python /home/gaowei/Music/src/report_time.py`

Comment: @Algebra Maybe I am too unexperienced but what do you mean by `&>`? If you want to redirect the output just use `>`. **UPD**: I think I understood that you wanted separately `&` and `>`. You need to have a space there `*/1 6-23 * * * /home/gaowei/Music/src/report_time.py & > /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem as mine, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43436895/16726236) solved my problem.

First, run `id your_user_name` to get your UID.

Then, modify your crontab entry from

```
*/1 6-23 * * * /home/<your_user_name>/Music/src/report_time.py &> /dev/null
```

to

```
*/1 6-23 * * * XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/<your UID> /home/<your_user_name>/Music/src/report_time.py &> /dev/null
```

If everything goes right, the problem will be solved.